# Apache Phoenix vs Hive-Spark

Tags: cassandra, hive, apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

What's faster/easier to convert into SQL, that accept SQL scripts as input: Spark SQL which comes as a layer of speed for Hive high latency queries or Phoenix? And if so, how? I need to do a lot of upserts/joining/grouping over the data. [hbase]

Is there any alternative on top of Cassandra CQL to support the above mentioned(joining/grouping in a real-time manner)?

I'm most probably bound to Spark since I would like to take advantage of MLlib. But for processing the data which should be my option to go?

Thanks,
kraster

Answer (score 3):

http://phoenix-hbase.blogspot.com/
I more then sure that Phoenix on Hbase will work faster.

here is sample query and PC requirement for test
Query: select count(1) from table over 10M and 100M rows. Data is 5 narrow columns. Number of Region Servers: 4 (HBase heap: 10GB, Processor: 6 cores @ 3.3GHz Xeon)
[image]
Because Phoenix use HBASE client interface to load all query, and use query engine only to map sql task for map reduce task in HBase

Comment: The question is about Hive-Spark. This chart doesn't mention whether Hive does MR or Spark. It seems the comparison is with Hive MR instead of Spark

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options (from my knowledge)

1. Apache phoenix is a good choice for low-latency and mid-size table (1M - 100M rows, but beware of tables with many columns!) processing. A great plus for phoenix is that its really easy to get started. My company already had an HBase cluster set up (with kerberos). To use Phoenix, all I needed was the HMaster URL, Hbase-site.xml and a keytab to get the operation going. Very quick reads and writes are decent (its slower for me because I needed to do it dynamically so I was force to use the Java client API instead of bulk loading)
2. Hive with Spark is great as well. I am not sure how great of a performance is it over Phoenix. Since Spark does most things in-memory, I am assuming it should be quick. However, I can tell you if you want to expose the SQL accessing as some sort of API, using spark becomes quite difficult.
3. Presto is a great product that offers Spark-like processing power with SQL interface that allows you to inter-connect data from many sources (Hive, Cassandra, MySQL ..etc)

Hope this helps.